# Why $\widetilde m = argmin_{m \in \mathcal P(X)} E[m]$ implies $\widetilde m (\arg \min \frac{\delta E}{\delta m}[\widetilde m]) =1$?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, calculus-of-variations

Consider $E: \mathcal P (X) \rightarrow \mathbb R \cup \{ \infty \}$ a functional (with a convex and dense domain, $E< +\infty$) over $\mathcal P(X)$ the set of probability measures of a metric compact space $X$.

Then consider the minimisation problem $\underset{m \in \mathcal P(X) }{\inf} E[m] $

Suppose that there is a $\widetilde m \in \mathcal P(X)$ solves the minimisation problem and that $E$ is differentiable in $\widetilde m$ is the sense that there is a function $\frac{\delta E}{\delta m}[\widetilde m]$ such that for all $m$ in the domain of $E$

$$ 0 \leq  \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{E[\widetilde m + \epsilon (m-\widetilde m)]-E[\widetilde m]}{\epsilon}\leq  \int_X \frac{\delta E}{\delta m}[\widetilde m] ~d(m -\widetilde m)$$

Then we have for all $m$ in the domain of $E$ $$ \int_X \frac{\delta E}{\delta m}[\widetilde m] ~d \widetilde m \leq  \int_X \frac{\delta E}{\delta m}[\widetilde m] ~dm .$$

How to conclude that $\widetilde m$ is concentrated on $(\arg \min \frac{\delta E}{\delta m}[\widetilde m]) $?

> Here is my idea. Since $$ \int_X \frac{\delta E}{\delta m}[\widetilde
> m] ~d \widetilde m \leq  \int_X \frac{\delta E}{\delta m}[\widetilde
>  m] ~dm $$
>
> folows for any $m$ so by taking $m(x) = \begin{cases} 1, ~\text{if } x
>  = \arg \min  \frac{\delta E}{\delta m} [\widetilde m]\\ 0, \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$
>
> we have
>
> $$ \int_X \frac{\delta E}{\delta m}[\widetilde m] ~d \widetilde m \leq
>  \arg \min  \frac{\delta E}{\delta m} [\widetilde m]$$
>
> but  $$ \arg \min  \frac{\delta E}{\delta m} [\widetilde m]\leq \int_X
>  \frac{\delta E}{\delta m}[\widetilde m] ~d \widetilde m \leq  \arg
>  \max  \frac{\delta E}{\delta m} [\widetilde m]$$
>
> therefore
>
> $$ \int_X \frac{\delta E}{\delta m}[\widetilde m] ~d \widetilde m =
>  \arg \min  \frac{\delta E}{\delta m} [\widetilde m]$$
>
> and so $\widetilde{m}(x) = \begin{cases} 1, ~\text{if } x = \arg \min 
> > \frac{\delta E}{\delta m} [\widetilde m]\\ 0,
> > \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Many thanks

Comment: If you are voting down could you at least let a comment to let me know your critics please ? Thanks in advance